# NFS/krb5 authentication server lookup fails due to wrong principal name

Tags: docker, kerberos, nfs4, freeipa

When mounting an NFSv4 with Kerberos, authentication fails and krb5kdc.log shows the wrong principal name for the NFS server.

```
LOOKING_UP_SERVER: ... host/nfsclient.internal.domain.tld@IPA.DOMAIN.TLD for nfs/containershost.internal.domain.tld@IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
... Server not found in Kerberos database
```

Principal **nfs/containershost.internal.domain.tld** should be **nfs/nfs.internal.domain.tld**.

Am I correct in assuming that a reverse DNS query is being performed which is returning **containershost.internal.domain.tld**?
If so, at what step in the process (and from which machine) does this lookup happen?

```
$ dig -x 192.111.111.111
111.111.111.192.in-addr.arpa. 6009 IN PTR containershost.internal.domain.tld.
```

Is there a way to prevent this reverse DNS query from happening? The host at IP 192.111.111.111 (containershost.internal.domain.tld) is running multiple containers and so adding PTR records isn't possible.

#### Docker Container Host

**Hostname:** containershost.internal.domain.tld
**IP:** 192.111.111.111

#### FreeIPA Server (docker)

**Image:** freeipa/freeipa-server:centos-8-4.8.4
**Container Name:** freeipa
**Container Host:** containershost.internal.domain.tld
**Hostname:** freeipa.internal.domain.tld
**IP:** 172.222.222.222
**Domain:** ipa.domain.tld
**Realm:** IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
**Keytab:**

```
$ klist -k /etc/krb5.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2 host/freeipa.internal.domain.tld@IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
```

**/etc/krb5.conf:**

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    rdns = false
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    forwardable = true
    udp_preference_limit = 0

[realms]
    IPA.DOMAIN.TLD = {
        kdc = freeipa.internal.domain.tld:88
        master_kdc = freeipa.internal.domain.tld:88
        admin_server = freeipa.internal.domain.tld:749
        default_domain = ipa.domain.tld
        pkinit_anchors = FILE:/var/lib/ipa-client/pki/kdc-ca-bundle.pem
        pkinit_pool = FILE:/var/lib/ipa-client/pki/ca-bundle.pem
    }

[domain_realm]
    .ipa.domain.tld = IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
    ipa.domain.tld = IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
    freeipa.internal.domain.tld = IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
    .internal.domain.tld = IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
    internal.domain.tld = IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
```

#### NFS Server (docker)

**Image:** ubuntu:latest
**Container Name:** nfs
**Container Host:** containershost.internal.domain.tld
**Hostname:** nfs.internal.domain.tld
**IP:** 172.333.333.333
**Running Services:**

```
- /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd --port 32767 --no-nfs-version 2 --no-nfs-version 3 -F --debug all
- /usr/sbin/rpc.idmapd -S -vvv -f
- /usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd --debug --port 2049 --no-nfs-version 2 --no-nfs-version 3 -L 10 -G 10
- /usr/sbin/rpc.svcgssd -f -vvv -rrr -iii -p nfs/nfs.internal.domain.tld
```

**Keytab:**

```
$ klist -k /etc/krb5.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  74 host/nfs.internal.domain.tld@IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
  66 nfs/nfs.internal.domain.tld@IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
```

**/etc/krb5.conf:**

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    rdns = false

[realms]
    IPA.DOMAIN.TLD = {
        kdc = freeipa
        admin_server = freeipa
        default_domain = domain.tld
    }

[domain_realm]
    .domain.tld = IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
    domain.tld = IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
```

#### NFS Client

**OS:** Ubuntu 20.04
**Hostname:** nfsclient.internal.domain.tld
**IP:** 192.444.444.444
**Keytab:**

```
$ klist -k /etc/krb5.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5 host/nfsclient.internal.domain.tld@IPA.DOMAIN.TLD
```

**Mount Command:**

```
$ sudo mount -vvv -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5p 192.111.111.111:/ /mountpoint
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5,vers=4.2,addr=192.111.111.111,clientaddr=192.444.444.444'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting 192.111.111.111:/
```

#### Result

**/var/log/krb5kdc.log:**

```
freeipa krb5kdc[288](info): TGS_REQ (4 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), 
DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23)}) 192.444.444.444: LOOKING_UP_SERVER: authtime 0, 
etypes {rep=(0)} host/nfsclient.internal.domain.tld@IPA.DOMAIN.TLD for nfs/containershost.internal.domain.tld@IPA.DOMAIN.TLD, 
Server not found in Kerberos database
```

Answer (score 0):

The nfs server resolves it's own name to **containershost.internal.domain.tld**. Thus, it looks for that name in keytab file. You probably should explicitly set the container name to **nfs.internal.domain.tld** (with -name option or host directive in docker-compose) or add yet another entry into keytab file.

Comment: On the NFS server, hostname -f returns nfs.internal.domain.tld. If the NFS server is resolving this name it's not due to its own hostname/fqdn.